# PHP создание каркаса приложения и Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

есть код config.php:

```
<?
require_once($config['basedir'].'/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->compile_dir = $config['basedir']."/temporary";
$smarty->template_dir = $config['basedir']."/themes";

$smarty->assign('baseurl',       $config['baseurl']);

for ($i=0; $i<count($lang); $i++)
{
    $smarty->assign('lang'.$i, $lang[$i]);
}
?>
```

этот код инклудится в корневом index.php (и везде где надо шаблоны)

```
<?php
include("include/config.php");

$smarty->assign('news',$news);

//TEMPLATES BEGIN
$smarty->display('header.tpl');
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
$smarty->display('footer.tpl');
?>
```

Можно создавать так экземпляр класса Smarty везде? (т.е. инклудим везде config.php с **$smarty = new Smarty();**) Т.е. используем всегда оперативную память на класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Можно создавать так экземпляр класса Smarty везде? (т.е. инклудим везде `config.php` с `$smarty = new Smarty();`) Т.е. используем всегда оперативную память на класс.

А вы знаете еще какие-то альтернативные способы? Это вполне обычный способ, и в целом не только для смарти.

зы: не совсем логичным выглядит передача N-ного числа переменных, вместо передачи простого массива в шаблон.

```
$smarty->assign('lang'.$i, $lang[$i]);
```

Comment: массив данных читается из файла, а не выполняется MySQL запрос

Comment: @Vytas а какая разница откуда он взят?

Comment: ну можно и массив передать...